# Mobile Keyboard hiding input field in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

There are multiple fields on my screen which is designed in unity. While filling downwards input is blocking due to the keyboard.

Unity never supports the auto-scrolling screen just like the native Android/iOS.
Also, One more problem is the user has to input into a Keyboard input instead of an actual input box

Please check this screenshot for better understanding. [image]

What would be the ideal way to overcome with this?

Answer (score 0):

[TouchScreenKeyboard](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchScreenKeyboard.html)

You have to detect when the keyboard is open and do some logic that scales, or re-anchors the text field.

Comment: Yes, We can achieve it by any patch but is this an ideal way?

Comment: @GhostRider I'd like to think there is but I haven't heard of it. We used this solution in my last job for a commercial project and it worked fine.

Comment: Can we implement back button just like the browser in unity?

Comment: Back button on android is mapped to `KeyCode.Escape`. So you can add custom functionality in the block following `if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Escape))`